# Button to control scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a problem with the button that control to scroll up and down. It works fine(scroll up) when i click up button for the first time but then the second time the scrollview not scroll up. what did i do wrong? here's the code:

create the scroll:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(38, 5, 90, 280)];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(90, 950)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled: NO];
[imageView addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

button action:

```
-(IBAction)upButtonPress:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"UP");
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y + 95)];

 }
-(IBAction)downButtonPress:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"DOWN");
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y - 95)];

 }
```

Comment: May be you mean [scrollView addSubview: imageView]; instead  [imageView addSubview:scrollView]; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the y value from your scrollview frame's origin each time. You should be using `scrollView.contentOffset.y` instead.

```
-(IBAction)upButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"UP");
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y + 95)];
 }

-(IBAction)downButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"DOWN");
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y - 95)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your button actions accordingly :

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, Y) animated:YES];
```

Where Y is the value of `scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentSize.height`.